# Default Javascript Event & Jquery Interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a proprietary e-commerce platform our company has developed. I'm involved strictly with the frontend development.

Unfortunately, a lot of the shopping cart is utilizing inline javascript events to post data to our database. I plan to convert the inline javascript to Jquery in the near future, but for now, they stay.

One specific problem I'm having is with a "Delete item from Cart" icon that's repeated on each line item in the cart. There's an inline javascript event that's utilizing backend Delphi code to delete the item from the cart:

```
document.SPI_KitFormName.SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.value='DEL';
document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';
```

I just added a Jquery dialog box to popup when this "Delete item from Cart" icon is clicked, asking the user to confirm. I added a "Delete Item" and "Cancel" button to the dialog box.

The problem I ran into was that when the icon was clicked, the inline javascript event would run prior to the dialog box jquery. I get that. So, I added to my jQuery code `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the inline javascript from running first. The problem is, I don't know how to reenable it when I hit the "Delete Item" button in the dialog box.

Here's my current code:

```
var currentForm;
$(function() {
    jQuery('#confirm-itemdelete').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 160,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Delete Item': function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(".deleteitembutton a").die('click');
                currentForm.submit();
            },
            'Cancel': function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('.deleteitembutton a').live('click', function(e) {
        currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirm-itemdelete').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: The `.preventDefaul()` call doesn't have anything to do with attribute-based event handlers.  It's for preventing the *browser* default action.  You don't have much control over event handler ordering in cases like this.

Comment: Why not convert your inline JavaScript now?  It seems like you are going to spend extra time and effort hacking around this interaction, rather than making it work correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is a not-uncommon problem given the habit of so many back-end systems to still insist on entangling themselves with the presentation layer via onclicks and the like. It's very frustrating.

I ran into this same situation due to JSF, which insists on doing everything with inline onclick events as well.

The solution is hacky, but works. What I do is upon page render, I grab all of the onclick attributes and then cache them as jquery data properties, then delete the original onclick.

I can then bind my own jQuery events to them and based on some logic, I can decide as to whether or not I want to fire off the original onclicks.

Example:

```
<span id="test" onclick="alert('onclick')">test</span>
```

After document ready, I cache the onclick:

```
$('#test')
    .data('inlineOnclick',$('#test').attr('onclick'))
    .removeAttr('onclick');
```

I then bind my own click event

```
$('#test') 
    .click(function(){
        if(confirm('delete this?')){
            //fire off original onclick event via anonymous function
            var anonFunc = eval("(function(){" + $(this).data('inlineOnclick') + "})");
            anonFunc.call(this);
        }
    });
```

Sample: http://jsbin.com/ebotam

THAT SAID, note that most folks will scream at you for using `eval` as apparently it's evil. It probably is. And there's maybe a better way to handle this, but it's worked for me as an OK workaround for now. And, besides, inline `onclick`s are evil too, so maybe fighting evil with evil is OK. ;)

Comment: Thanks, all. It looks like the general consensus is that I was approaching the problem incorrectly. Instead of trying to control the order of event-firing, it's probably best to remove the onclick attribute right away. I'll try the various solutions and report back. If anyone else has another approach, I'm happy to look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this:

```
currentForm.submit = function(){
   return false;
}
```

I think this will prevent the form from submitting, then set it to true when you want it to submit.

Comment: The problem is that the onclick will fire first, then the confirmation dialog, so you'd be setting this value after-the-fact. Though you could re-fire the form submission via javascript at that point, so this could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way you might get this to work. On document ready run a script that rips out all the inline code of the offending elements and store that as a string in the elements' data attribute. And you'll need a higher level variable to store which button you're clicking on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonClicked; // Lets you know which one was just clicked.
    $('.deleteitembutton a')each(function(){
        $(this).data('cEvent', $(this).attr('onClick'));
        $(this).removeAttr('onClick');
    });
}
```

I don't know which attribute the in-line script is tied to so replace 'onClick' with whatever attribute it is in.

After you've done that you'll need to modify your dialog code a bit and create a new event.

```
// Add this to the 'click' event
buttonClicked = $(this);

// The new event
$('.deleteitembutton a').on('newEvent', function() {
    eval($(this).data('cEvent'));
}

// Add this line to your 'Delete Item' button in your dialog
$('.deleteitembutton a').trigger('newEvent');

// Add this to your 'Cancel' button in your dialog
buttonClicked = '';
```

Like I said, this is quick and dirty but it might just do the trick.